# fade in each div when it comes into view

Tags: jquery, scroll, fadein, scrolltop

I know how to fade in a div when it comes into view... My current function is doing that. The issue is that when the first div comes into view, all the divs fade in. However I want each div to fade in when each one comes into view. This is my current function:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var mywindow = $(window);
    var mypos = mywindow.scrollTop();

    $(".textDiv").each(function() {
      var currentDiv = $(this);
      if (mypos > $(currentDiv).offset()["top"] - mywindow.height()) {
        $(currentDiv).fadeIn(500);
      };
    });

  });
```

Comment: You're setting `var currentDiv = $(this);`, but then you're doing `$(currentDiv)`. You can just do `currentDiv` on it's own because it's already set as an array object.

Answer (score 1):

You might want something like [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/1eLs0cw9/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".block").before("<p>Block under here</p>");
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var mypos = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(".block").each(function () {
        if (mypos > $(this).offset().top - 150) {
            $(this).css('opacity', 1);
        };
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    padding-bottom: 200px;
}

.block {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Or something like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/1eLs0cw9/2/) to keep using fadeIn

Answer (score 0):

If your elements are set to `display:none;`, `$(currentDiv).offset()["top"]` will always return 0.

You need to use the element above the first hidden one as a pointer for where you need to check for scroll location.

You can use `$('.textDiv:hidden:eq(0)');` to find the first hidden element in your instance and then use `.prev()` to find the previous element.

Full code below:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ltd9rhrm/3/

```js
var ScrollTimer;
var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
function checkLoc(mywindow, mypos) {
    var $this = $('.textDiv:hidden:eq(0)');
    var $prev = $this.prev();
    if ((mypos + mywindow.outerHeight()) >= ($prev.offset().top + $prev.outerHeight())) {
        $this.fadeIn(500);
    };
}
function fireScroll() {
    pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    checkLoc($(window), pos);    
}
$(window).scroll(function () {
    ScrollTimer && clearTimeout(ScrollTimer);
    ScrollTimer = setTimeout(fireScroll, 100); // Make it only fire when you stop scrolling
});
checkLoc($(window), pos);
```

```css
.header {
    height:500px;
    background:red;
    border-bottom:5px solid black;
}
.textDiv {
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
    background: rgb(169, 228, 247);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169, 228, 247, 1) 0%, rgba(15, 180, 231, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(169, 228, 247, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(15, 180, 231, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169, 228, 247, 1) 0%, rgba(15, 180, 231, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169, 228, 247, 1) 0%, rgba(15, 180, 231, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169, 228, 247, 1) 0%, rgba(15, 180, 231, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(169, 228, 247, 1) 0%, rgba(15, 180, 231, 1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#a9e4f7', endColorstr='#0fb4e7', GradientType=0);
    border-bottom:5px solid black;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="textDiv"></div>
<div class="textDiv"></div>
<div class="textDiv"></div>
<div class="textDiv"></div>
<div class="textDiv"></div>
<div class="textDiv"></div>
<div class="textDiv"></div>
```